# Unable to use find -name correctly

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find, regex-greedy

1. Could anyone give some examples how to use `find -name "pattern"` command, especially with `"pattern"`s, where is used '**?**' as part of regular expression. Because my patterns match in online regular expressions, bit doesn't work in 'find' utility.
2. Could anyone explain what does this mean in find manual with examples?

> The metacharacters (`*',`?', and `[]') match a`.' at the start of the base name (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CONFORMANCE below)

1. How correctly use `"?"` in `find -name "pattern"`? Am I correct that `"?"` means "zero or one symbols"?

Answer (score 3):

From the `find` man page:

> -name **pattern**  Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches **shell pattern** pattern.

The answer to your question is the definition of the term *shell pattern*, which is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html) (you'll also find an explanation looking in the man page of your shell):

*****    Matches any zero or more characters.

**?**    Matches any one character.

**[string]**
    Matches exactly one character that is a member of the string string. This is called a character class. As a shorthand, string may contain ranges, which consist of two characters with a dash between them. For example, the class ‘[a-z0-9_]’ matches a lowercase letter, a number, or an underscore. You can negate a class by placing a ‘!’ or ‘^’ immediately after the opening bracket. Thus, ‘[^A-Z@]’ matches any character except an uppercase letter or an at sign.

**\**
    Removes the special meaning of the character that follows it. This works even in character classes.

---

**Examples**:

I hope the following examples explain the difference between `?` and `*`.

```
touch foobar
touch fobar

# * matches the tail (finds 'foobar')
find -name 'foo*'

# * matches the head (finds both files)
find -name '*bar'

# ? matches the 'f' at start (finds 'foobar')
find -name '?oobar'

# ? DON'T matches the whole tail (finds nothing)
find -name 'foo?'

# ? matches the second 'o' (finds 'foobar')
find -name 'fo?bar'

# ? matches one instance of any character after the 'f' (finds 'fobar')
find -name 'f?bar'

# * matches both zero or more characters after 'o' (finds both files)
find -name 'fo*bar'
```

This example shows how to use the bracket operator `[string]`:

```
touch fobar
touch fubar

# matches a single 'o' OR 'u' (finds both files)
find -name 'f[ou]bar'
```

Of course you are free to mix the various metacharacters:

```
# Finds every file starting with an 'o' or 'u' (included files named 'o' or 'u')
find -name '[ou]*'

# Finds every file starting with an 'o' or 'u' (excluded files named 'o' or 'u')
find -name '[ou]?*'
```

Comment: To be clear, `fo*bar` matches `fo`, followed by zero or more characters of any kind, followed by `bar`. The `*` is not related to the preceding `o`, as it is in a regular expression.

Comment: Thx for the clarification @chepner. I've edited that part to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. one example:

   [root@v3 ~]# find -name 'op?n*.sh'

   ./openerp-install.sh

   [root@v3 ~]# find -name 'op?en*.sh'

   [root@v3 ~]#
2. basename is the name of the file without the path, for example if file full path is "/usr/share/pkgconfig/gnome-icon-theme.pc", then the basename of that file will be "gnome-icon-theme.pc"
3. "?" in the find pattern means "exactly one symbol", not "zero or one symbol"